# ActiveRecord custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I assign a custom attribute to an ActiveRecord model?
For example, I can do it when querying via:

```
  select("(CASE WHEN wishlist_items.id IS null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS is_wishlisted_by_me").
```

This adds a custom `is_wishlisted_by_me` attribute. But what if I already have an instance of an AR model and I want to do:

```
model.is_wishlisted_by_me = true
```

this returns a `NoMethodError: undefined method`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_wishlisted_by_me=' for #<SIImage:0x007fc8c41c7ef8>
    from /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method` is not sufficient.. undefined method name is also need to be known.. Give the full error stack.

Comment: @Priti updated with stack

Comment: @0xSina where have you written this line?

model.is_wishlisted_by_me = true

Comment: I guess Rails doesn't add new attribute to the AR class, it just add the attribute to the returned objects of the select, that is why you can't use it with pre-existing AR object.

Comment: I also guess Rails will not create custom attribute for the alias column if AR class already have an attribute with the same name, so attr_accessor does not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with this way, define attr_accessible in your model:

```
attr_accessible :user_count

r = User.find_by_sql("select count(*) as user_count from users")

puts r.first.user_count
```

If a hash will do for you, you may try

```
User.connection.select_all("select count(*) as user_count from users")
```

which will return an array of hash like [{:user_count => 1}]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done:

```
after_initialize do
  self.is_wishlisted_by_me = nil unless @attributes.key?("is_wishlisted_by_me")
end

def is_wishlisted_by_me
  @attributes["is_wishlisted_by_me"]
end

def is_wishlisted_by_me=(value)
  @attributes["is_wishlisted_by_me"] = value
end
```